# Create multi-level array based on leading dashes in value

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have the following array:

```
$options = array(
  'a' => 'Test 1',
  'b' => '-Test 2',
  'c' => '-Test 3',
  'd' => '--Test 4',
  'e' => '--Test 5',
);
```

I want to transform this in a multi-level array, with each dash representing one level deeper. So this array should become:

```
Array(
  [Test 1], => Array(
    [b] => 'Test 2',
    [Test 3] => Array(
      [d] => 'Test 4',
      [e] => 'Test 5',
    )
  )
)
```

I currently got this working for one level deep, but I'd like to create a function that handles any amount of levels deep. This is what I do now:

```
  $list = array();
  foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    if($value[0] == '-') {
      if (!isset($list[$lastvalue])) {
        unset($list[$lastkey]);
        $list[$lastvalue] = array();
      }
      $value = substr($value, 1); // remove the leading dash
      $list[$lastvalue][$key] = $value;
    }
    else {
      $list[$key] = $value;
      $lastkey = $key;
      $lastvalue = $value;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I believe you should use recursion

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense:   'b' => '-Test 2',
  'c' => '-Test 3', should be in the same level.

Comment: No, the item above the one with a leading dash becomes the parent, with its value becoming the key. That's why I work with a $lastkey and $lastvalue in the code I currently have.

Comment: So how come test 4 and test 5 are in the same level?

Comment: The `array should become` logic is wired. Why is `c` not anymore found. Why is `Test 2` a value but `Test 3` a key? They where equal at the start array. Both have one `-` ??

Comment: Test 5 would only become an array with 'Test 5' as key when another item would be added with three dashes, for example `'f' => '---Test 6'`.

Comment: `array(  'a' => 'Test 1',  'b' => '-Test 2',  'c' => '-Test 3',  'd' => '--Test 4',  'e' => '-Test 5','f'=>'---Test 6')` What happens here?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions `Test 3` is a key because it is followed by an element with one dash extra, e.g. `--Test4`.

Comment: My problem is that if you iterate over it (take your example), you first make `Test 2` an value, then `Test 3` a value, but then you get `Test 4` and have to move `Test 3` from value to an key. That is quit wired: key can be value. And are the letters `a b c d` really needed?

Comment: `Test 1` becomes a key because the following element, `Test 2` has one extra dash. `Test 3` becomes a key because the following element, `Test 4` has one extra dash.

Comment: The logic behind the code syntax is clear, evething else not. Hard to make an general/failsafe function for this, if the logic behind this isnt clear. Also the use of letters as key isnt clear here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to rome...

```
$opt = array(
    'a' => 'Test 1',
    'b' => '-Test 2',
    'c' => '-Test 3',
    'd' => '--Test 4',
    'e' => '--Test 5',
);
$tmp=array(); $lvl=null;
foreach(array_reverse($opt) as $idx => $set){
    $clean = ltrim($set,'-');
    if(!is_null($lvl)){
        if($lvl == substr_count($set,'-')){
           $tmp[$idx] = $clean;
        } else {
           $_tmp[$clean]=is_array($tmp)?$tmp:ltrim($tmp,'-');
           $tmp = $_tmp;
           $_tmp = array();
           $lvl = substr_count($set,'-');
        }
    } else {
        $lvl = substr_count($set,'-');
        $tmp[$idx] = $clean;
    }    
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($tmp);
print '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [Test 1] => Array
        (
            [Test 3] => Array
                (
                    [e] => Test 5
                    [d] => Test 4
                )
            [b] => Test 2
        )
)
```

Works also with deeper levels, if the given array is ordered right.

Comment: This looks great, thanks! It is important the the letters as keys are also incorporated though.